# Can Master Zhou use Qi Gong to heat aluminium foil?

Tags: chi

[Master Zhou Ting-Jue](http://www.masterzhou.com/) appeared on *[That's Incredible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That%27s_Incredible!)* in the early 1980s.

Amongst his claims were that Qi gong allowed him to raise the temperature of a piece of aluminum foil. See this [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/vkfvv9lEXPM?t=3m21s).

Does this video demonstrate that Master Zhou can remotely heat a piece of aluminium foil using only chi?

Comment: You should quote/describe in detail  the specific claim/event happening in the video (and ideally provide screencaps).

Comment: I focussed this question right down to one claim. I confess I cherry-picked a claim that is easy to address. Please open another question about other specific claims that Master Zhou makes if you are interested in those too.

Answer (score 5):

(I'm assuming you refer to the scene with the thermograph in the orthopedic surgeon's office.)

The man in the lab coat is [Dr. Michael D Roback](http://www.warbrittonassociates.com/doctors/michael-roback-m-d), the other man is [Zhou Ting-Jue](http://www.masterzhou.com/).

Colin Wright offers as explanation ["a dilute strong base such as sodium hydroxide"](http://anamericanatheist.org/2013/08/21/investigating-woo-master-zhou-qigong-healer-debunked/) in the water, reacting with the aluminium foil to generate the heat. While this is not positive proof that Zhou is a fraud, it shows that there is an alternative explanation that is at least as credible as the one initially claimed. Lacking further information and/or more reliable expert opinions, the video cannot be considered a "demonstration" of remote heating *only* through Qigong, so the answer is "no".

Comment: May I ask the reason for the downvote? The question is not about debunking Zhou, but about whether the video shows remote heating.

Comment: Clarified why Wright's explanation invalidates the claim about the video.